# How do I loop a program based on user input?

Tags: python

I'm wondering how I make a loop based on user input?

```
import random

die1 = random.randrange(6) + 1  
die2 = random.randrange(6) + 1
total = die1 + die2

raw_input("Ready to roll dice 1? Press enter if you are.")
print "You rolled a", die1, "with dice 1."

raw_input("Ready to roll dice 2? Press enter if you are.")
print "And a", die2, "with dice 2."

print "Giving you a total of", total
```

If after giving the `total` the user wanted to roll again, how would I do that? `Ideally Press 1 to play again or press 2 to exit.`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the whole thing in a while loop. In the code below you press 1 to continue or any key to quit:

```
import random

replay = True

while(replay):
    die1 = random.randrange(6) + 1  
    die2 = random.randrange(6) + 1
    total = die1 + die2

    raw_input("Ready to roll dice 1? Press enter if you are.")
    print "You rolled a", die1, "with dice 1."

    raw_input("Ready to roll dice 2? Press enter if you are.")
    print "And a", die2, "with dice 2."

    print "Giving you a total of", total
    replay_option = raw_input("Press 1 to play again or press any key to exit")

    if replay_option == '1':
        replay = True
    else:
        replay = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your dice rolls in a while loop. After the total is printed, use raw_input to have the user enter the value of a variable. 
`myVar = raw_input("Enter 'y' to roll again or anything else to quit:  "`
Make the condition of the while loop `while myVar == 'y':`
Don't forget to set myVar equal to 'y' before the loop.